# R: Trim strings on import or trim x-axis labels

Tags: r

I have a barplot where the data that makes up the x-axis is far too long to display properly. The basic format is "ABCD1234-Really, really, really, long subsequent text string". How can I get R to just display the first X characters?

Comment: Grant, welcome on stackoverflow. Please don't let the downvote of your question frustrate you but improve your question by adding a minimum code snippet that makes your problem reproducible for all of us.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know for sure since you offer not code or even variable names, but perhaps something along the lines of:

```
 ...  <plot code> , labels=unique( substr( Xax_var, X)) )
```